# Does this stochastic convergence hold?

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains, random, ergodic-theory

Let $(u_k)_{k\geq 1}$ a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}u_k=+\infty$.

Let $(X_k)_{k\geq 1}$ a sequence of identically distributed random variables, taking their values in $\{0,1\}$, such that $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=p\in (0,1)$. Note that I do not assume the $X_k$'s to be independent. Let's say they form a stationary Makov chain.

Do we have, almost surely,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_ku_k=+\infty$$
?

If we had $p=1$, this would just be a Cesaro sum and the result would hold. But here we randomly cancel an infinite number of terms. My intuition is that we have this result provided that $u_k$ goes to $+\infty$ fast enough (at least linearly?). However, I don't know how to prove that, as we cannot directly apply the ergodic theorem for Markov chains.

Comment: If $u_k \ge k^{1+\alpha}$ for $\alpha >0$ and if $\{X_k\}$ is irreducible, then if $X_n=1$, we have that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \ge n^{\alpha}$. As the event $[X_k =1 i.o]$ has probability one, we would get the desired result. In fact it would hold for anything faster than linear.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it was true if $u_k\geq k$ for $k$ large enough.

Comment: Please then post your conclusion here, I am sure other people will find useful in the future.

Comment: Does the case where $X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = \dots = 1$ with probability $p$ and $X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = \dots = 0$ with probability $1-p$ fall under your "Markov chain" case? That would definitely be a counterexample.

Comment: @Kernel in fact my proof was false. I understand your idea, but it seems to me that it just proves that the limsup is $+\infty$.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I will see if I have any other ideas.